# Raphael js problems with mouse events in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, raphael, mouseevent

Working with Raphael library, I've got a lot of problems with mouse events in Safari (it just doesn't work on mouse events).

I read it's common, and maybe there is a solution for this (from the documentation):

> `Paper.safari()`
>
> There is an inconvenient rendering bug in Safari (WebKit): sometimes
>   the rendering should be forced. This method should help with dealing
>   with this bug.

by the way, I can't understand how to make it works..
I do like this:

```
var Paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById("paperId"), '300px', '300px');
Paper.safari();
```

can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
or, otherwise, is there an alternative solution?

I've been searching for hours, with no results... :(

edit:
yes, the problem is about filling a raphael element with an url:

```
myClass.prototype.PhotoClick = function(){
    var that = this;
    $('.photo').each(
           function(){
                $(this).dblclick(function(event) {
                                        that.loadPhoto[index].attr({fill:"url(images/image1.jpg)"});
                                        });
            });
}
```

sorry, I don't post more, because the code is a bit messy.
however, the array item is a raphael object, and the url path is correct.
if I fill the element with a color, everything is fine. just urls give me problems...

hope now it's clearer

Comment: that function is meant for fixing render quirks, not mouse event issues. please describe the problems you're having in more detail, and provide relevant code snippets.

Comment: try and wrap the URI value with quotes, e.g. `fill:"url('images/image1.jpg')"`.

Comment: nope..i tried, but the problem seems the be other. do you know any good documentation about raphael and Safari rendering bug? I can't find anything.. :(